# Does somebody know the current status of Graphics32?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, graphics32

The last release of [Graphics32](http://www.graphics32.org/) 1.8.3 is dated with March 2007.

When will there be an *official* Delphi 2010 compatible version?

Is there any public SCM repository of Graphics32?

Comment: Keep wondering why anyone would vote for closing this. It's a very legitimate question, on a programming topic, about the state of a widely used project. Aren't we a tad bit trigger happy?

Comment: Yes, ... I can't comprehend the close-vote too, ...

Comment: They are some people who abuse the close.  They used to abuse the offensive flag too.  Some how makes them feel important to close things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is now a [1.9 release](http://graphics32.org/wiki/Main/Release) (March 2010), with Delphi 2010 support.
The project is still alive ! take a look at [changes](http://graphics32.org/documentation/Docs/Overview/Changes.htm).

Answer (score 4):

No official release yet, but I have been trying to push things forward as an outsider. There is now a port available that is working on D2009/D2010. Currently the ports is available for download from one of our web servers until an official version is posted. See notice here: [Graphics32 RadStudio 2010](https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=154673)

Answer (score 3):

You could try asking that on the mailing list here: [news.graphics32.org](http://news.graphics32.org). [This search for "delphi 2009" on that page](http://graphics32.org/news/newsgroups.php?search_txt=%22delphi+2009%22&search=Search&group=graphics32.general) currently yields this result:

[Graphic32 & delphi 2009](http://graphics32.org/news/newsgroups.php?art_group=graphics32.general&article_id=8832)

No, there is no public SCM repository.

Comment: This is reportedly being addressed. Graphics32 is moving to SVN in the near future AFAIK

Answer (score 2):

Bumping this: Graphics32 is now hosted at Sourceforge as of October 2009. Still no new version or official support for Delphi 2009 or 2010.